# unsetting session array value in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my session array:

```
[inactivefilter] => Array
    (
        [0] => add
        [1] => new
    )

[filter] => Array
    (
        [0] => new
    )
```

'Add' and 'New' are dynamically generated by the user.

I currently send the value of the array to my controller, then am stuck on what the model should do.

```
    public function clear_filter()
    {
        $i = $this->input->post('filtervalue');
        $this->thread_model->clear_filter($i);
    }
```

`$i` would equal whatever value they click on.  So if they clicked 'add' `$i = add`

I need to unset both activefilter and filter based on whatever the value of $i is.  Is there an easy way to do it?

I've read about array_splice, array_diff, and some other ways, but had no success.

Comment: Are you using CodeIgniter's sessions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using codeigniter sessions:

```
$filter = $this->session->userdata('filter');
$index = array_search($i, $filter);
unset($filter[$index]);
$this->session->set_userdata('filter', $filter);
```

Using php sessions:

```
$index = array_search($i, $_SESSION['filter']);
unset($_SESSION['filter'][$index]);
```